# Does @EnableBinding annotation disable the Functional Approach automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-11, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have a microservice that utilizes a custom binder, `CustomBinderA`, and a declarative approach. In the code, you can find several classes with annotations like `@EnableBinding`, `@Input`, `@StreamListener`, and so on. Everything works fine.

Recently, I implemented another binder, `CustomBinderB`, and tested it on a different microservice using the latest functional approach, and everything worked well there too.

Now, I am attempting to integrate the new binder into the previous microservice while still keeping the old one. Every configuration point is enabled, and everything should work. However, I noticed that only the explicitly declared bindings (i.e., those with the `@Input` annotation) are being instantiated.

So, the only thing I am trying to figure out is: can the functional approach and the declarative approach work together, or is there some way in which, if `@EnableBinding` is used, the properties related to the functional approach are being ignored?

I tried to combine both the configurations using the multibinder approach.

```
spring:
  cloud
    stream:
      function:
        definition: createOrderConsumer

      binders:
        CustomBinderB:
          type: custom-binder-b
        CustomBinderA:
          type: custom-binder-a


...
      bindings:
        createOrderConsumer-in-0:
          destination: createOrder
          binder: CustomBinderB
        outbox:
          destination: notifyOrder
          binder: CustomBinderA
        inbox:
          destination: inbox
          binder: CustomBinderA
```

I expected every bindable channel to be instantiated.

However, only the "inbox" and "outbox" channels are being instantiated, which are the ones explicitly declared using the @Input and @Output annotations.

Answer (score 0):

`EnableBinding` and all related components, such as `Input` and `Output` etc., have been deprecated for a while now and completely removed from the recent versions of the framework (starting with `4.0.0`). Therefore, we highly recommend to stop using `EnableBinding` in your application and migrate completely to the functional style. If you are using a version of Spring Cloud Stream that still supports `EnableBinding`, it is not advised to mix both styles in a single application.